# Is it possible to design custom tattoos in SIMS 4?

Tags: the-sims-4

I am aware that we can select a tattoo for our sims from a range of available tattoos in *Create A Sim menu*, either from a dresser or a mirror. However, as they are limited, I am wondering if there's a tattoo parlor (or a machine) that allows us users to **generate custom tattoos**? I have seen mentions of tattoo machines in SIMS 4 forums but I have never seen one in the game-play.

Would be great if it could be found in the original game itself.

But if not, a mod would also be okay.

Comment: It's a bit too lengthy for me to put into an answer but please see this in-depth tutorial: https://simscommunity.info/2021/10/29/tutorial-how-to-make-custom-tattoos-for-the-sims-4/